# Arduino Bluetooth and Ultrasonic Distance Sensor (HC-SR04): printing values over BT gives error

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, serial-communication

I'm trying to send the reading distance of an HC-SR04 sensor to an Android app, using Bluetooth. I succesfully managed to send values from many other sensor to the app, but when it comes to sending the HC-SR04 reding, a strange behaviour happens.
To send the reading over BT I use a simple `Serial.printl(value)` command, which also display the reading on the PC serial monitor.
The strange thing is this: if the bluetooth module is disconnected, the readings are correct, but as soon as I connect the Bluetooth module on the breadboard (a JY-MCU), the reading start to get apparently random, even I watch at them on the PC monitor, and not from the app. I still haven't figured out if this problem is hardware or software related.

I also tried to disconnect all the other sensors and components from the circuit, using a vary basic sketch, but the result is the same: as soon as I insert the Bluetooth module ( even if the data is not sent to the Android app), I start getting random distance values.
Here is the sketch:

```
int trig = 10;
int echo = 7;
void setup(){ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  long distance = getUltrasonicAltitude();
  Serial.println(distance);
}
long getUltrasonicAltitude(){
  long duration, cm;
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echo,HIGH);
  cm = duration/29/2;
  return cm;
}
```

I tried using the `newPing` library, and even using interrupts instead of the `pulseIn` function to get the time between the pulses, but the result was always the same: everything was ok but only without the bluetooth module...

Do you know a way, or have a suggestion, to fix this annoying issue that has been bugging me for two days? It may be an hardware or a software issue, so I'm really open to hear any kind of possible solutions.

Comment: Are these sharing power supplies?   Did you wire power directly to the modules, and bypass them, or did you cheat and try to power them from GPIO pins as some tutorials unwisely suggest?  If you substitute a constant value for the reading in your program, but leave everything connected, does the constant value come through cleanly?  If you have access to a scope, is the echo pulse stable?  If not the echo timing is slow enough you can probably use a PC soundcard to fake a scope...

Comment: Yes, both modeles (HC-SR04 and JY-MCU) share the same power source, which is the 5v and GNS pins of Arduino. They are obvioulsy connected in parallel. As you suggested, I tried sobstituting the reading with a constant value, and this is fine. Unforunately I haven't access to an oscilloscope... So do you think the problem is related to the time required by the bluetooth module to serial print the value, which affect the pulseIn function?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the reason of the issue! Using a voltmeter I found out that the problem basically is that the bluetooth module absorbs too much current every time the Serial.println function in called, and this causes the voltage to oscillate up and down, between 3.8 and 4.3 volt. It seems that the ultrasonic range sensor doesn't like that. Is there any way to fix this problem without using an other external power supply? Maybe a capacitor can smooth the voltage drops?

Comment: This is a question for electronics.stackexchange.com